# could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig' in search paths

Tags: ios, flutter

$flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

When i try to build on Xcode, i have this issue:

```
Showing Recent Messages /ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig' in search paths
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the terminal, navigate to the project by typing:

   cd your_file_path
2. After that navigate to the iOS folder by typing:

   cd ios
3. Finally, fix your problem by implementing the missing podfile by typing:

   pod init
4. Then, open the newly created podfile, follow instructions in the file (which tell you to remove a comment on the second line of the file).
5. Close your Flutter project, and reopen it.
6. Run your project again.

if it is not working, following this way

navigate ios/Podfile file and uncomment platform :ios, '9.0'(remove #)

Answer (score 1):

Try running `flutter build ios` and then rerun in Xcode